# table looping xml xsl is not displaying

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I need to use below xml code file and xsl code file in order to display content on the browser.  for some reason, I cannot figure out anything:

The display should look like following, but I cannot figure out what in the world I need to do:
[image]

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="invoices.xsl"?>
<invoices>
<invoice number="25" date="February 28, 2001">
<patient firstname="Jeff" familyname="Smith" SSN="123456789">
  <phone type="home" number="123-4567890"/>
  <phone number="321-76543321" type="work"/>
  <address type="home" line1="123 Street" city="City" state="US" zip="12345"/>
</patient>
<insurance name="Humongous First Medical Insurance" plannumber="12345" planname="The Client Company">
<phone number="098-76543321"/>
<address type="business" line1="321 Street" city="City" state="US" zip="54321"/>
</insurance>
<procedure code="123" name="Cleaning nose" cost="50.00" insurance_estimate="50.00"/>
<procedure code="124" name="Tarot reading of illnesses" cost="150.00" insurance_estimate="120.00"/>
<procedure code="125" name="Just for fun" cost="100.00" insurance_estimate="80.00"/>
</invoice>
<invoice number="27" date="February 28, 2001">
  <patient firstname="James" familyname="Smith" SSN="123456765">
     <phone type="home" number="123-4562245"/>
     <address type="home" line1="432 Street" city="City" state="US" zip="12343"/>
   </patient>
   <insurance name="Humongous Second Medical Insurance" plannumber="3455" planname="Another Client Company">
      <phone number="098-76543321"/>
      <address type="business" line1="344 Street" city="Some City" state="US" zip="54323"/>
   </insurance>
   <procedure code="123" name="Cleaning nose" cost="50.00" insurance_estimate="50.00"/>
   <procedure code="124" name="Tarot reading of illnesses" cost="150.00" insurance_estimate="120.00"/>
 </invoice>
 <invoice number="29" date="February 28, 2001">
<patient firstname="Neil" familyname="Smith" SSN="123456345">
  <phone type="home" number="125-4345890"/>
  <address type="home" line1="187 Street" city="Lost City" state="US" zip="42145"/>
</patient>
<insurance name="Humongous Third Medical Insurance" plannumber="12345" planname="The Lost City Client Company">
  <phone number="198-76345321"/>
  <address type="business" line1="342 Street" city="Completely Lost City" state="US" zip="111111-0000"/>
</insurance>
<procedure code="123" name="Cleaning nose" cost="50.00" insurance_estimate="50.00"/>
<procedure code="125" name="Maybe they wouldn't see this line..." cost="100.00" insurance_estimate="80.00"/>
</invoice>
</invoices>
```

XSL file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFE0">
<!--    -->
<TABLE border="0" width="100%">
<xsl:for-each select="/invoices/invoice">
<tr>
<td>
<H1>Invoice #
<xsl:value-of select="@number"/>,<BR/>
<xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
</H1>
<TD align="right"><img src="sax_extractData_logo.gif"/>
</td>
</td>
</TR>
</xsl:for-each>
<!--   -->
 </TABLE>  
<TABLE border="0" width="100%">
  <TR valign="top">
<TD>
  <xsl:for-each select="/invoice/patient">
        To: <xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@familyname"/>
        <BR/>Account #<xsl:value-of select="@SSN"/>
        <BR/>
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@line1"/><BR/>
        <xsl:if test="address/@line2!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="address/@line2"/><BR/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@city"/>,
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@state"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@zip"/><BR/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</TD>
<TD>
    <xsl:for-each select="/invoice/insurance">
        Insurance: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><BR/>
        Plan name: <xsl:value-of select="@planname"/><BR/>
        Plan #<xsl:value-of select="@plannumber"/><BR/>
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@line1"/><BR/>
        <xsl:if test="address/@line2!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="address/@line2"/><BR/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@city"/>,
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@state"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="address/@zip"/><BR/>
        <xsl:value-of select="phone/@number"/><BR/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<P> </P>
<TABLE border="1" width="100%">
  <TR>
<TD width="20%">Code</TD>
<TD width="20%">Name</TD>
<TD width="20%">Cost</TD>
<TD width="20%">Insurance estimate</TD>
  </TR>
  <xsl:for-each select="/invoice/procedure">
  <TR>
<TD width="20%"><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></TD>
<TD width="20%"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></TD>
<TD width="20%"><xsl:value-of select="@cost"/></TD>
<TD width="20%"><xsl:value-of select="@insurance_estimate"/></TD>
  </TR>
  </xsl:for-each>
</TABLE>
<P> </P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, rather than write a whole load of XSLT and wonder why it is not working, take a step back, and start with something simple that does work, and build upon that. You have started off all right with selecting the individual invoices, so you could initially just get it to output invoice numbers

```
<xsl:for-each select="/invoices/invoice">
   <H1>
       Invoice #<xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
   </H1>
<xsl:for-each>
```

But your problems lie with how you select the **patient** element. You are doing this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="/invoice/patient">
```

But there are two problems. Firstly, this is an absolute expression, not relative to the node you are currently positioned on. The first `/` represents the top-level document node, so it is looking for root node of **invoice** in the XML, which does not exist.

Secondly, the loop is in the wrong place anyway. It needs to go inside the **xsl:for-each** loop for selecting **invoice** elements, not after it. Then, you can write this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="/invoices/invoice">

    <xsl:for-each select="patient"> 
         To: <xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/>    <xsl:value-of select="@familyname"/>
         <BR/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note how the expression is now **patient** and relative to the current **invoice** item. You would do similar for the **insurance** and **procedure** elements.

Actually, it is better to use **xsl:apply-templates** here, rather than **xsl:for-each**, as if nothing else it avoids excess indentation. So, your **for-each** statement becomes this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="patient" />
```

And then your have a separate template to output the details

```
<xsl:template match="patient">
    To: <xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/>    <xsl:value-of select="@familyname"/>
    <BR/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT as a starter. Note, I am not outputting many HTML tables here, or all of the fields, but it should give you idea, so you can build upon it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <HTML>
         <BODY bgcolor="#FFFFE0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="invoices/invoice" />
         </BODY>
      </HTML>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="invoice">
       <H1>
          Invoice #<xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
       </H1>
       <img src="sax_extractData_logo.gif"/>
       <br/>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="patient" />
       <xsl:apply-templates select="insurance" />
       <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="procedure" />
       </table>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="patient">
       To: <xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/>    <xsl:value-of select="@familyname"/>
       <BR/>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="insurance"> 
       Insurance:  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
       <BR/>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="procedure"> 
        <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to use same template again.  It simply replaces the first name for example.  Also, How do I use another template in the same line?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "use same template again" as all the templates in the XSLT above are different. Have a look at http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8k to see it in action.